# Extract Data/controls from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Currently I have a word document that is a questionnaire.

Format (Total of 30 questions):

Name:

```
1. Question
YES checkbox
NO checkbox
Comments

2. Question
YES checkbox
NO checkbox
Comments
```

The check boxes and comments are controls.

What I am trying to do is extract the checkbox and comment data into excel. For example,

```
1. Do you spend time under the sun?
YES checkbox is selected
Comments: I spend 2 days out of the week in the sun.
```

What I want it to display in excel would be.

[image]

Every time the macro is run, it should add the new information below an existing record (row).

I usually use Word and extract data from excel into word, but I have never tried this one.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, iCtr As Long, cBox As CheckBox, StrFlNm As String
    With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        SendKeys "%n *.doc ~"
        If .Show = True Then
            StrFlNm = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    Application.Volatile

    For Each cBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If cBox.Value = 1 Then
            iCtr = iCtr + 1
        End If
    Next cBox
    CheckedCount = iCtr
End Sub
```

It goes as far as selecting the file, but nothing happens. If i can identify how to apply it to one checkbox, I should be able to figure out how to do the rest. I will be updating the code as we go on, I have changed it numerous times.

Activated Microsoft Object and ran the new code. Once the file is selected, I am prompted with this message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first half of your code does nothing more than give you a file name. At that moment, Excel knows nothing about the content of the document.
Here, you will need to open the document, and for that you need a reference to Word's object model. 
In Tools - References, select *Microsoft Word nn Object Library*.
Now, Excel can work with Word documents.

Do something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, iCtr As Long, cBox As ContentControl, StrFlNm As String

    With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        SendKeys "%n *.doc ~"
        If .Show = True Then
            StrFlNm = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Application.Volatile

    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Set Doc = Word.Documents.Open(StrFlNm)
    Debug.Print Doc.Range.ContentControls.Count

    For Each cBox In Doc.Range.ContentControls
        If cBox.Checked Then
            iCtr = iCtr + 1
        End If
    Next cBox
    CheckedCount = iCtr
    Doc.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Making progress. Once the file is selected, I get an error popup, but the error message is blank. I will post the error message. @Sam

Comment: Remove the entire  `With` block temporarily and hardcode `StrFlNm`. That will help you find out where the problem lies

Comment: For some fully-fledged code, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/19914-how-transferring-word-data-excel-sheet.html#post59665

Comment: Sam, I don't see anywhere in the code where you instantiate the Word application. I expect that's why @LOZ is getting an error. The code in the question is running in Excel, so there's no Word application to open a Word document...

Comment: @CindyMeister - I tried just now. It works without explicit instantiation.

Comment: @macropod Hi Macropad, I used the code you had provided and it is working well, just need a few adjustments. For example, in each of the questions there are two checkboxes (Labeled as Yes or no). Regardless of which checkbox is clicked, in excel it creates two columns for each checkbox (Each column will represent True or False depending which one is checked). I want one single column showing only the checkbox that was selected.